# Mongoose $or query does not work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am perplexed. Separate queries work fine, but with the $or, don't.

```js
//combined query does not produce any reuslts
User.find({
     $or: [{
       $text: {
          $search: keyword,
       },
     }, {
       'skills.name': {
          $regex: keyword,
          $options: "i",
       },
     }],
    active:true,
});

//this query produces results
User.find({
  'skills.name': {
      $regex: keyword,
      $options: "i",
   },
    active:true,
});

//This query produces results as well
User.find({
  $text: {
     $search: keyword,
  },
  active:true,
});
```

```js
//this does not produce results either
User.find().or([{
   $text: {
     $search: keyword,
   },
 }, {
  'skills.name': {
    $regex: keyword,
    $options: "i",
 },
}])
```

There is no errors, just no results.

What am I missing?

Comment: try: `{$and: [{$or: [{$text: {$search: keyword}},{'skills.name': {$regex: keyword, $options: "i"}}]}, {active:true}]}`

Comment: when using $text with $or, all clauses in the $or array must be supported by an index.  check this link.(https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/#or-and-text-queries)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT: nope, did not work (no results)

Comment: @vijay - all clauses are supported by index, here's what I have: userSchema.index({headline: 'text', summary: 'text', skills: 'text'});

Comment: try `$regex: new RegExp(keyword),`

Comment: I ended up using $regex instead of $text in all parts of $or, and it worked. So it had to do something with text indexing.